# Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I'm trying to add login functionality to my website and I'm using typescript with mognoose and I'm getting this `Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'` error [image].

getUserFromLogin

```
const getUserFromLogin = async (email: string) => {
    await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
        try {
            const res = await UserModel.findOne({
                email,
            });

            return res;
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    });
};
```

User Schema:

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IUser extends Document {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

interface reqStringInterface {
    type: StringConstructor;
    required: boolean;
}

const reqString: reqStringInterface = {
    type: String,
    required: true,
};

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
    id: reqString,
    username: reqString,
    email: reqString,
    password: reqString,
});

export const UserModel = model<IUser>("User", userSchema);
```

I'm pretty sure that the fix will be to add a return value in the getUserFromLogin function but when I add `Promise<any>` it throws this error `Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'`. Thank You!

Comment: `getUserFromLogin` is an `async` function, it returns a _promise_ of... actually, of undefined. But once you've made it a promise of the user, you'll still need to resolve that in the request handler, with `.then` or `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getUserFromLogin` does not return anything, because your `return res` is inside of an arrow function. To avoid this sort of confusion try not to mix `then` and `await` syntax in one method, you can re-write like this:

```
const getUserFromLogin = async (email: string) => {
    const mongoose = await mongo();
    try {
      const res = await UserModel.findOne({email});
      return res;
    } finally {
      mongoose.connection.close();
    }
};
```

And then you'll need to await the promise

```
let user = await getUserFromLogin(email)
```